# how can i get the previous value on keyup event or the next value on a keydown event (without using jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, html, web

is there any way to get the coming value of a "keydown" event? or alternatively the previous value of a "keyup" event? i found this question on many places but all of them got a solution with using jQuery (which i don't use).

Comment: Hi, I don't quite understand what you mean. Both the keydown and the keyup events will give you the key that is being/was pressed.

Comment: if i'm adding 'c' to 'ab', keydown event.target.value will return 'ab', and keyupEvent.target.value will return 'abc'.

i want to have the full current value and the full previous value at the same time

Comment: Are you looking for event.key? That gives the character. event.code gives the type of key pressed e.g. keyA (whether it was a or A).

Comment: i'm looking to know in the same function that the previous value was 'ab' and the currency value is 'abc'. the fact that i know that the new key is 'c' is not enough since the user could have put the 'c' in the middle of the text

Comment: Thanks, I'd misunderstood. I think you'll have to remember the value on keydown and compare it with the value on keyup otherwise, as you say, the positioning is lost.